# Updating column in sqlite table iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, sql-update

I am updating column in sqlite table it works fine but i think when each time method is called for updating value i think mix ups update value to other record if there is one record then it is fine if we have two records then i think it gets mix up here is the code for updating

```
    - (void)addContentViews:(NSString *)dbPath {

   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   NSLog(@"The Content ID is %@",appDelegate.contentID);

  //if(updateStmt == nil) {


    NSLog(@"The Content ID is %@",appDelegate.contentID);


    NSString*select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE ContentMaster Set Views = ? where contentID ='%@'",appDelegate.contentID];


    const char *sql = [select UTF8String]; 


    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {    

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

         // }


   sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt,1, [views UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

         if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
     //else
    //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid


   // contentID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);


//Reset the add statement.


    sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but (a) you called `sqlite3_reset` (which is for resetting a prepared statement so you can bind new values and call `sqlite3_step` again) where I suspect you intended `sqlite3_finalize` (which is for freeing the memory allocated during the `sqlite3_prepare_v2`); (b) you probably want everything from the prepare through the finalize to be inside the `if` clause of the successful open (i.e. wrap that all inside braces). Right now, if open fails, you'll skip the prepare, but you'll still try to bind, step, and finalize; and (c) did you mean to close the database?

Comment: @Rob can you please edit in my code so that i can understand what to use thanks

Comment: I've modified your question replace `sqlite3_reset` with `sqlite3_finalize` and added missing braces around so that `if` database open failed, it not only doesn't prepare, but also doesn't bind, step, or finalize, either. I also fixed `if` statement for the step command, so that if you got an error, it will still finalize the prepared statement.

Comment: Why don't you use Fmdb for Sqlite operations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to confirm how many rows were updated, call `sqlite3_total_changes(database)` before and after the call, look at the difference between those two values, and that will tell you how many rows were updated.

If more than one row is getting updated, then I suspect that you have more than one row with the same `contentID` value. You should look at your database on the simulator (on the simulator, it's in the `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` folder ... if you don't see your `Library` folder listed (because it's generally hidden), you can unhide it from the Terminal command line with `chflags nohidden ~/Library`). Just open up that database in your SQLite tool of choice (either the Terminal `sqlite3` command line program or whatever tool you prefer) and take a look at it.

Comment: @AijazAli If you're still having problems after you've dug around a little, show us examples of some of your data. But I suspect that if you compare your logged `appDelegate.contentID` and the values in the database before and after, the issue will probably become self apparent.